# How to get relevant month and date by inputting only the day of year in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

I'm developing a phonebook application from python as a mini project in which I'm having the requirement to store the NIC number of a person and then display his/her gender, DOB and age. I have to derive these 3 information and I'm able to derive the gender, but I don't know how to derive the DOB - only the birth year because the NIC number's first 2 digits represent the year of birth.

In a NIC number, the 3rd three digits are the day of year :- from 001 to 366. I can seperate those 3 digits to another variable as well, but how do I derive the month and the date of month which it refers to?

For example :

```
derivedYear = 1996
dayOfYear = 032

finalDOB = "1996.02.01"
print finalDOB
```

I want to know how to calculate the finalDOB value. I'm using python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%j` format for day of year in `datetime.datetime.strptime()` , to get the corresponding datetime object . Example -

```
>>> derivedYear = 1996
>>> dayOfYear = 32
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(dayOfYear, derivedYear),'%j %Y')
>>> d
datetime.datetime(1996, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

Then you can use the `.day` and `.month` attribute of the datetime object to get the corresponding day and month. Example -

```
>>> d.day
1
>>> d.month
2
```

If you want the result in format - `YYYY.MM.DD` - you can use `strftime()` and supply the format to it. Example -

```
>>> d.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
'1996.02.01'
```

---

Also, please note, you should not define your `dayOfYear` with a leading `0` , as that would make the literal an octal number, which would not be what you want.

Comment: I'm having another minor issue... dayofyear 060 in a leap year refers to Feb. 29th. But in a non leap year, 060 refers to March 1st. According to the NIC format, regardless of leap or non leap year, they issue numbers for all 366 days. If a non leap year, 060 is not issued and march 1st is represented by 061, like in a leap year... 
But how can I implement this in my Python program? I tried 
dayOfYear += 1, but still it gives the output as March 1st for 060 in a non leap year.

Comment: You seem to be taking at it wrongly , instead of adding 1 for leap years, you should subtract 1 for non leap years . And after subtracting use datetime for the conversion .

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta). It can take days as an argument, and when added to a date, will shift it by that amount.

```
import datetime

year = 1996
days = 32

date = datetime.date(year, 1, 1) #Will give 1996-01-01
delta = datetime.timedelta(days - 1) #str(delta) will be '31 days, 0:00:00'
newdate = date + delta

>>> str(newdate) 
>>> 1996-02-01
```

or

```
>>> newdate.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
>>> '1996.02.01'
```

Comment: I got this error - 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test2.py", line 4, in <module>

    date = datetime.datetime(year)

TypeError: Required argument 'month' (pos 2) not found

Comment: @PraveenFernando Sorry, I forgot you need to give month and day in datetime. Just updated code. try again :)

Comment: yup, it's ok... I tried... your method gives me the output 1996-02-01 00:00:00 with time.. thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: @PraveenFernando You can change `datetime.datetime(...)` to `datetime.date(...)` and it will remove the `00:00:00` I've updated the code :)

Comment: I see... Thanks alot mate! the datetime.date() also worked!